# form won't display value after calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to do some calculation but it does not seem to work.
I need to perform calculations on the data the user inputs and then display the results. 
I don't seemed to be able to get the output for b and c. Is there a difference if i divide by a decimal/decimal?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() { 
                            var x = document.getElementById("energycost").value; 
                            var y = document.getElementById("peak").value; 
                            var z = document.getElementById("nonpeak").value; 
                            var k = document.getElementById("input").value; 
                            var b = x / (y + (z / k)); 
                            var c = b / k; 
                            document.convert.output1.value = b;
                            document.convert.output2.value = c; 

                            }
    </script>
    <body>
    <FORM ACTION="#" NAME="convert">
                        Step 1:<br>
                        Enter the Fixed Tariff cost($/kWh)
                        <input type="text" id="fixed"SIZE=6
                            onblur="multiply.call(this,this.form.elements.energyload.value,this.form.elements.fixed.value)">

                        Enter the Total Energy load value(kWh)  
                        <input type="text" id="energyload"SIZE=6
                            onblur="multiply.call(this,this.form.elements.energyload.value,this.form.elements.fixed.value)">    
                        <BR><BR>
                        Total Energy load cost($)   
                        <input type="text" id="energycost"SIZE=6 DISABLED>

                        <BR><BR>
                        Step 2: <br>
                        Enter Total Peak Energy load value(kWh)
                        <input type="text" id="peak"SIZE=6>

                        Enter Total Non-Peak Energy load value(kWh)
                        <input type="text" id="nonpeak"SIZE=6>  
                        <BR><BR>    
                        Step 3:<br>
                        Enter K value
                        <input type="text" id="input"SIZE=4
                            ONKEYUP="myFunction()">
                        <BR><BR>


                        <input type="text" id="output1" DISABLED>

                        TOU Peak Price
                        <input type="text" id="output2" DISABLED>
                        TOU Non-Peak Price
                        </FORM></body>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  When you step through the code in a debugger (such as FireBug or Chrome tools), does it behave as expected?

Comment: `document.convert.output1.value = ...`

Comment: try place your javascript function _after_ the HTML ...

Comment: I don't see where you defined `document.convert.result` let alone output1 and output2. Also your JavaScript is merged with your HTML! JavaScript needs to be in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: sorry about that, i saw that mistake, erm basically my question is more pertaining towards this equation var b = x / (y + (z / k)); var c = b / k; when i tried input the field for y and z and k as decimal figures, i will get nan. is there an error like c like overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see where your `result` comes from.

This could be the solution (though I didn't try it, keep me posted):

```
document.convert.output1.value = b
document.convert.output2.value = c
```

Comment: ya it is sorry about that, but the problem i am trying to ask is the equation more towards var b = x / (y + (z / k)); var c = b / k; when i tried input the field for y and z and k as decimal figures, i will get nan. is there an error like c like overflow? do i have to float my variables like c?

Answer (score 0):

I'd parseInt() on those values or do some validation on the user input, and as pointy added,

document.convert.output1.value = b;